# UWP C# Image from streamreader ( request post )

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to put a chart in my UWP application, so the easiest way i found is using a Image controle in my wfp and get the image chart from googleapis_chart 
but how to converte StreamReader to Image ?

```
        string postString = "cht=lc&chs=180x180&chxt=x&chd=t:"+data;
        WebRequest req_googlechart = WebRequest.Create("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart");
        req_googlechart.Method = "POST";
        req_googlechart.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream stream_googlechart = await req_googlechart.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(stream_googlechart);
        await requestWriter.WriteAsync(postString);
        requestWriter.Dispose();
        WebResponse rep_googlechart = await req_googlechart.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader reader_googlechart = new StreamReader(rep_googlechart.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: image1.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(reader_googlechart .BaseStream);

Comment: also, look into using `using` to not have to manage all that dispose stuff yourself.  you might be leaking a lot of stream things in the above.

Comment: @sTrenat No BitmapFrame.Create() in uwp :/

Answer (score 0):

The type of `reader_googlechart .BaseStream` is `Stream`, you could convert it to `BitmapImage` with the following code. And set image source with `BitmapImage`.

```
Stream res = reader_googlechart.BaseStream;
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    await res.CopyToAsync(mem);
    mem.Position = 0;
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(mem.AsRandomAccessStream());
}
this.img.Source = bitmap;
```